# How to shuffle 2D Array in JavaScript using random function and is it possible to populate 2D array with 3 specific double values like 0 , 0.5 , 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, double

Lets say this is the array i want to shuffle randomly, what would be the most efficient way to do so?
How could i populate this kind of array with three specific values (0, 0.5, 1) but in random order each time i start the program?

`Can i use something like " a[i][j] = rand.nextDouble() " ?`

`Double a[][] = {{0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5},`
`{0, 1, 0, 1, 1},`
  `{0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0},`
     `{0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0},`
`{1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1},`
 `{0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5},`
  `{0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1}};`

I tried generating this array with`a[i][j] = (rand..nextDouble() * (1-0))+0.5;`but it turns out values like 1.2 and 0.3 etc, is there a way to increase random values by 0.5 only? so that they can be in range from 0-1?

Thank you!

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: thanks, my bad, first time using this platform.

Comment: @JanPeters First time or not, you should edit your question to fix errors.

Comment: Are you using commas for decimal places? I know many countries do that, but it makes it hard to read your list of alternatives. Also note that you are inconsistent - are the three values supposed to be {0, 0.5, 1.5} as in your first paragraph, or {0, 0.5, 1} as in your code fragment?

Comment: I use point " . " for decimal places.
I corrected the title - thank you! the values are supposed to be ( 0, 0.5, 1 )

Comment: @JanPeters Please proofread your question. It still contains inconsistencies with use of commas and desired range of values. You may consider these nitpicking details, but details can be critical in programming (and are often the source of the errors people come here to ask about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to generate a new random number you can add the required numbers into an array and generate a random index to choose the numbers.

```
import java.lang.Math;

class MainRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double arr[][] = new double[5][7];
        double num[] = { 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                int rand = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4));
                arr[i][j] = num[rand];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 1.5 0.5 0.0 
0.0 0.5 0.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.0
1.5 0.5 1.5 1.0 1.5 0.0 1.0
1.0 0.0 1.5 0.5 0.0 1.0 1.5 
0.5 1.5 0.0 1.5 0.5 0.0 0.0
```

Printing the 2d Array ^

Answer (score 1):

Generate an integer between 0 and 2 (inclusive) – 0 and 3 (exclusive), then divide by 2. This will give you 0.5 steps (1/2 = 0.5).

To initialize your array, create a function to return a random array of 5 values. Then call this method 5 times and assign it to each index of your top-level array.

Comment: OP’s question is inconsistent but the first paragraph says three specific values. Generating 0 to 3 inclusive yields 4 values.

Comment: @jps: true. The title asks for [0, 0.5, 1.5], but the text itself uses [0, 0.5, 1] and highlights the "0.5 steps". Dividing by 2 will give 0.5 steps. Anything else and OP has to be more specific. Is it 0-1.5 (without 1) or is it 0-1 (with 0.5 steps)?

Comment: thank you i missed the mistake it should be 0-1 with 0.5 steps so 0 & 0.5 & 1